# pandas objects created by bs4 & regex elements are being printed as python lists

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping house data from [zoopla.co.uk](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine)

I'm getting the data I want but three elements are being printed to the csv file and dataframes as python lists. The two elements `bathrooms` and `bedrooms` are strings so they get printed correctly, but the other three elements that were found by using regex, `house_price`, `house_type`, and `station_distance` are printed as lists types.

Should I not be using regex and be using bs4 only? I cannot simply just use the replace function right? Thanks in advance.

Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'
res = requests.get(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
lis = soup.find("ul", class_="listing-results clearfix js-gtm-list").find_all("li", class_="srp clearfix")

for li in lis:
    bedrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-beds")
    bathrooms = li.find("span", class_="num-baths")

    price = li.find("a", class_="text-price")
    house_price = re.findall('\£(\d+)', str(price))

    style = li.find("h2", class_="listing-results-attr")
    house_type = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(style))

    distance = li.find("li", class_="clearfix")
    station_distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(distance))

    if bedrooms:
        bedrooms = bedrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if bathrooms:
        bathrooms = bathrooms.get_text(strip=True)
    if house_price:
        house_price = house_price
    if house_type:
        house_type = house_type
    if station_distance:
        station_distance = station_distance

    df = pd.DataFrame({'house_price': house_price, 'house_type': house_type, 'station_distance': station_distance, 'bedrooms': bedrooms, 'bathrooms': bathrooms})
    print(df)

    df.to_csv('zoopla.csv')
```

Output

```
house_price house_type  station_distance    bedrooms    bathrooms
0   [90]    [flat]  [0.2]   1   1
1   [210]   [detached house]    [0.6]   3   None
2   [160]   [end terrace house] [0.7]   2   1
3   [325]   [detached house]    [1.2]   4   1
4   [195]   [semi-detached house]   [1.1]   3   1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are printed like list because you are using **findall**,

```
house_price = re.findall('\£(\d+)', str(price))
house_type = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(style))
station_distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(distance))
```

You can keep the first element (inside each *if*)

```
house_price = house_price[0]
house_type = house_type[0]
station_distance = station_distance[0]
```

or try with find (like you did with *bathrooms* and *bedrooms*).

Comment: The subscripting works a treat. Thank you. I thought the text from those 3 variables `house_price`, `house_type`, `station_distance`  required a regex to find the text. Can they be found without a regex??? Could you please add an example of using the `find()` function like you were suggesting?  Thanks!!